# Show a Min Max Text in a MPGraph in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, graph, linegraph, mpchartios

I am trying to show a min max values in a MP graph, so I have drawn a circles in a line graph. I want to show a Text as Min and Max at that point. How should I achieve it in android.

[image]

As shown in image above, I have two circles in the graph, These circles are the min and max value in a chart. But I also want a text with these circles as "Min" and "Max" in the graph

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/yaxis/) to get an idea how to implement this feature on the `YAxis`.

---

**Always `0` as min value** use `setStartAtZero(boolean enabled)`:

If the `boolean` is `enabled`, the axis will always have it's minimum value at zero, no matter which kind of data the chart displays.

---

**Max and Min in value:**

`setAxisMaxValue(float max)`: Set a custom maximum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.

`setAxisMinValue(float min)`: Set a custom minimum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.

---

**Max and Min in percent:**

`setSpaceTop(float percent)`: Sets the top spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the highest value in the chart in comparison to the highest value on the axis.

`setSpaceBottom(float percent)`: Sets the bottom spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the lowest value in the chart in comparison to the lowest value on the axis.